# SPSS merging two datasets - some different variables, no duplicate cases/rows

Tags: spss

I have two SPSS files (.sav). The two files have some different variables (columns) and they have completely different rows/cases. I know that SPSS can "add variables" or "add cases", but I need to do both.

I want to merge the files together, keeping all variables from both files.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `"Add cases"` (`"Data/Mergefiles/Add cases..."`), and you will be prompted to choose which variables to keep in the new datafile. Simply add all available variables (from both files) when prompted (there will be a dialogue; move all variables from the list on the left into the list on the right)

If the two files have common variables, they will be merged into a single variable, assuming they also have the same format (e.g. - you won't be able to merge variables with the same names, if one is numeric and the other one is string).

Comment: also, if two variables with the same name are both strings, you have to make sure they are both the same width.